# Wildcard Sub-Domain Redirect using only DNS

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain with working sub-domains like,

```
valid-1.mysite.com
valid-2.mysite.com
```

And I would like to redirect all non-allocated sub-domains like,

```
something.mysite.com
abcdefghi.mysite.com
```

to my root domain(mysite.com).

Is there any way to implement using Wildcard DNS records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put in wildcard A and AAAA records that make all the non-explicitly-assigned names under mysite.com have the same IP addresses as mysite.com. This will not magically make a web server serving mysite.com know that it should also serve all those non-specified names.

Comment: I tried adding a wildcard A, and the DNS did resolve my site to IP, but all I got is a 404 from Web server... Is there any tweaks that can be made on web server to accept such incoming wildcard connections?

Comment: Probably, but that depends entirely on the web server and has nothing to do with DNS.